# Instagram publick profil data

Tags: json, instagram, instagram-api

Instagram changed api. Is there anyway to get data that was on this link: https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/{userID}/info/

or get data form only public profiles if closed profil are disabled?

Comment: i am in the same boat having the same error, which is that endpoint not working

Comment: you can use , https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_self 
but for that you will need the user to authorize your app to get an access_token token